# Проблема с поддоменом

Tags: поддомены, хостинг

Всем привет!

На Infobox создал A-запись для поддомена (сайт размещен на VPS hc.ru). Теперь заходя на поддомен, вижу строку "Apache is functioning normally". Почему не открывается сайт?
На хостинге пробежался по directAdmin, наткнулся на панель редактирования httpd.conf. Подозреваю, что нужно в ServerAlias добавить поддомен, но не понимаю как она работает. Прописал просто ServerAlias поддомен.свойдомен.ru и сохранил, но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: после изменений необходимо перезагружать сервер Apache. Если и это не помогает, приведите пример настроек из вашего httpd.conf

Comment: перезагружал, не помогло. http.conf сюда не влезает. видимо, тут вопрос в большей части по directadmin. В нем создан один основной домен, для которого указаны алиасы (эти домены привязаны к одной CMS). К одному из алиасов нужно добавить поддомен, но непонятно как. если создать как новый домен (sub.domain.ru), то создается новая директория sub.domain.ru, куда и попадаем по новому адресу. а нужно чтобы sub.domain.ru смотрел в уже существующую директорию с CMS.